Running Vite dev mode on Symfony 7 application with DDEV webserver
I've been looking to run Vite in development mode (watch JS and CSS files) for my Symfony 7 app which is served with a DDEV webserver.
// package.json
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
}

Now, https://my.ddev.site is running fine and my assets are loaded great when using $ npm run build. But using $ npm run dev is not working for me. It seems my assets are loaded from the wrong host in development mode. They are loaded from:
<script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/build/assets/app.js"></script>

Where I would want it to be:
<script type="module" src="/build/assets/app.js"></script>

Ideally I want my assets to be watched on development mode and the browser automatically updated.
I've tried loading a different host, proxy or other settings with in vite.config.js:
// vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import symfonyPlugin from "vite-plugin-symfony";
import autoprefixer from "autoprefixer";

/* if you're using React */
// import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        /* react(), // if you're using React */
        symfonyPlugin(),
        autoprefixer
    ],
    server: {
        // host: "https://my.ddev.site", // Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://my.ddev.site
        // origin: 'https://my.ddev.site', // Does update the asset path but ends up in a loop
        proxy: {
            // Using the proxy instance
            '^/': {
                target: 'https://my.ddev.site',
                changeOrigin: true,
                configure: (proxy, options) => {
                    // proxy will be an instance of 'http-proxy'
                },
            },
        },
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                app: "./assets/app.js"
            },
        }
    },
});

but no luck so far. Can someone help me? I don't know if this helps but I'm working on MacOS
Thanks!

After reading https://ddev.com//blog/working-with-vite-in-ddev/ (thanks @rfay) I've added this to my DDEV config:
// .ddev/config.yaml
web_extra_exposed_ports:
    - name: vite
      container_port: 5173
      http_port: 5172
      https_port: 5173

Restarted DDEV
Added this to vite.config.js:
const port = 5173;
const origin = `${process.env.DDEV_PRIMARY_URL}:${port}`;

export default defineConfig({

    // Adjust Vites dev server to work with DDEV
    // https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html
    server: {
        // respond to all network requests:
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: port,
        strictPort: true,
        // Defines the origin of the generated asset URLs during development
        origin: origin
    }
    
});

Now the path is correct but I'm getting a CORS error:
Access to script at 'http://my.ddev.site:5173/build/@vite/client' from origin 'http://my.ddev.site' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Getting closer, still not working

Welcome to Stack Overflow and DDEV! One of the best references is https://ddev.com//blog/working-with-vite-in-ddev/, and Matthias keeps that updated. See if that helps. You might want to come over to the DDEV Discord to chat with him as well,  https://discord.com/invite/5wjP76mBJD

If you're stumbling on the same error and you're looking for a solution, this did the trick for me:

Make sure your have SSL installed
$ mkcert -install
Restart ddev service
$ ddev poweroff
Start your app
$ ddev start
Restart Vite
$ ddev npm run dev
Visit your app in the browser my.ddev.site and reload the page

After these steps, I was still getting a CORS error in my browser, but this time a little different. I did the following steps and after that worked for me:

Visit https://my.ddev.site:5173 in the browser
Return to your app in the browser and reload the page again.

